# ggplot align main axis.ticks length with minor axis.ticks length

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's assume the x-axis is running from 0-100. I want to get the following specifications:

1. Tick marks and labels at 20s, i.e., at 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, and 100,
2. Tick marks of same length without labels at 10s, i.e., at 10, 30, 50, 70, 90,
3. Tick marks of 50% length without labels at 5s, i.e., 5, 15, 25 etc.

One idea that came to my mind is the use of `geom_segment()` to place the additional tick marks (2 and 3). However, this requires to specify `y` and `yend`, while the tick marks require to specify the length in units, e.g., "cm". Is there an easy solution to place the additional tick marks relative to the length of the main tick marks, or at least in the same unit?

As can be seen from the exemplary chart, the placement of the tick marks works as expected, but the length of the tick marks is not aligned.

[image: example]

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000, mean = 50, sd = 10),
                 y = rnorm(1000, mean = 50, sd = 7))

# obtain difference between breaks with and without labels
xminor <- setdiff(seq(0, 100, 5), seq(0, 100, 20))
segment_data = data.frame(
  x = xminor,
  xend = xminor, 
  y = 0,
  yend = ifelse(xminor%%10 == 0, 3, 2)
)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_segment(data = segment_data,
               aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y, yend = yend)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 20),
                     labels = seq(0, 100, 20), 
                     limits = c(0, 100),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, linewidth = 0.5),
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, color = "black"),
    axis.ticks.length.x = unit(-0.5, "cm"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by removing the axis ticks completely and using a `polylineGrob` annotation at the exact locations and with the exact lengths you want. This also means you don't need the `segmentdata` data frame.

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  annotation_custom(grid::polylineGrob(
                      x = rep(0:20/20, each = 2), 
                      y = unit(rep(c(0, 0.5, 0, 0.25), length = 42), 'cm'),
                      id = rep(0:20, each = 2))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 20),
                     limits = c(0, 100),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, linewidth = 0.5),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = margin(10, 20, 10, 20))
```

[image]

Note that this also works for ticks external to the plotting panel if you set `coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')`

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  annotation_custom(grid::polylineGrob(rep(0:20/20, each = 2), 
                      unit(rep(c(0, -0.5, 0, -0.25), length = 42), 'cm'),
                                    id = rep(0:20, each = 2))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 20),
                     limits = c(0, 100),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, linewidth = 0.5),
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = NA),
    axis.ticks.length.x = unit(0.5, 'cm'),
    plot.margin = margin(10, 20, 10, 20)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
```

[image]